# ThreadPoolExecutor keep waiting when exception happens

Tags: python-3.x

```
from asyncio import FIRST_EXCEPTION
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue
from concurrent.futures import wait
import os


def worker(i: int, in_queue: Queue) -> None:
    while 1:
        data = in_queue.get()
        if data is None:
            in_queue.put(data)
            print(f'worker {i} exit')
            return

        print(os.path.exists(data))


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        queue = Queue(maxsize=2)

        workers = [executor.submit(worker, i, queue) for i in range(2)]

        for obj in [{'fn': '/path/to/sth'}, {}]:
            fn = obj['fn'] # here is the exception
            queue.put((fn,))

        queue.put(None)
        done, error = wait(workers, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        print(done, error)


main()
```

This program get stuck when exception happens.

From the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 31, in main
    print(done, error)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 623, in __exit__
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 216, in shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1044, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It happens because `wait` function keep locked, but it's weird because the exception happens before the `wait` function. It should be returned when exception happens!!

Why it doesn't return immediately when exception happens?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I find the reason. When the exception happens,  executor will exit, and in `with` statement, it calls `self.shutdown(wait=True)`, so main thread waits for sub thread to exit, however sub thread keep running.

So the solution is that, shutdown the executor manually with `wait=False`：

```
try:
    ## code here
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    executor.shutdown(False)
```